# How can we play on Heroes of Newerth (HoN) latin america on mac?

Tags: macos, heroes-of-newerth

Some time ago, S2 Games prohibited latin america players to play on the international server. They threw the responsibility to cope with annoying brazilians to Axeso5.

With that, whoever have a Mac and don't want to install Windows on it, "can not" play HoN anymore, because Axeso5 doesn't have and is never planning to have support for mac. No OSX clients whatsoever!

So, other than getting a life, choosing another game or moving to a better country, is there any solution to that? Or even if I live in a place I could play on international...

What if I just wanted to play on the so called "lan" on my mac? Is there a way?

<sup>disclaimer: There is a way and I just made it work. I'll wait and see if someone can answer it and save me the work of posting it. Also, I can actually play on international using VPN, obviously. So, yeah, this is just feeding! :-P</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All [thanks](https://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/showthread.php?450956-Axeso5-HoN-doesn-t-have-a-Mac-or-Linux-client&p=15361039&viewfull=1#post15361039) to [*theli*](https://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/member.php?81901-theli)**.

> First things you need:
>
> - An Axeso5 account, you can register one via the website
> - Installed native client for your system ( download at http://heroesofnewerth.com/download.php )
>
>   1. **Unpack [launcher](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4443078/HoN/garena/launcher.tgz)** into your HoN installation directory
>   2. (**For MacOSX users**) Right click "Heroes of Newerth.app" > "**Show package contents**"
>   3. Launch **lat.command** ( eg with double-click )
>   4. Enter your login and password on login screen
>
> Launcher is just a python script - so anyone can open it and make sure it is not stealing your account info or something like that.
>
> If someone is interested he can follow launcher development at github: https://github.com/theli-ua/garenahon

On step (3), I actually [made a wrapper for the launcher, to hide the terminal window](https://superuser.com/a/612072/28411):

> Open [**Automator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_%28software%29), choose **Application**, add a **Run Shell Script** action and *put in your Shell command **between quotes*** (just drag and drop `lat.command` into it). You can save it (as an app anywhere) and even set the icon (by going to `CMD + I` and dragging the original HoN app into the info window).